# Pause a game loop that uses 'requestAnimationFrame()'

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm trying to add the Pause functionality to a game loop I have:

```
GameLoop = {

  //Insert more members here if needed

  run : function(options) {

    var now,
        dt       = 0,
        //last     = timestamp(),
        last     = Date.now(),
        slow     = options.slow || 1, // slow motion scaling factor
        step     = 1 / options.fps || 60,
        slowStep = slow * step,
        update   = options.update,
        render   = options.render;


    function frame() {
        //now = timestamp();
        now = Date.now();
        dt = dt + Math.min(1, (now - last) / 1000);
        while(dt > slowStep) {
            dt = dt - slowStep;
            update(step);
        }
        render(dt / slow);
        last = now;
        requestAnimationFrame(frame, options.canvas);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(frame);

  }

};
```

I've used some documentation and tutorials to get to this structure and I already have a game that seems to work perfect with it.

Is there a way I can add a function like 'pause' so it stops, then I can resume it whenever I want and continue normaly?

**Let me know if you need more code or any additional iformation, thanks!**

Comment: Add a bool variable in the game object that you can flip called `isRunning`. When `isRunning` is false, don't run the content in the frame function.

Comment: Pausing a game is usually not done by stopping the render loop, but by skipping the simulation steps inside the loop. Many games have animations even on the pause screen.

Comment: Also, why do you have a second parameter on `requestAnimationFrame`?

Comment: @hege_hegedus ermm, I saw it on a document I was reading about game loops in javascript, I don't know if it makes a difference actually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either you don't call the handler recursively in case of stop, or you can cancel requested function by [cancelAnimationFrame()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/cancelAnimationFrame).

Comment: Thank you, that link had a loop that looked kinda like mine, I managed to make it work with my code!

Comment: But keep in mind that cancelAnimationFrame browser support isn't well. So it depends on the browsers you need to support.

Comment: Working perfect on Chrome and FF. Haven't tried IE 11 tho